# partial differential equation with delta function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dirac-delta, wave-equation

I don't get the following equation:
$$
\square\frac{\delta(r-ct)}{r}=-4\pi\delta(\vec{r})\delta(r-ct)
$$
Where the square is the D'lambert operator.
$$
\square=\nabla^2-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}
$$
Is this equation true? How would I prove it?

Comment: Can someone clarify the meaning of the product of delta functions? i.e. what value do you assign to the integral of that against a test function? Thanks.

Comment: @BobTerrell Actually, the right-hand side should be written more appropriately as $-\frac{4\pi}{c} \delta(\vec r)\delta(t)$.  Heuristically, $\delta(\vec r)\delta(r-ct)=\delta(\vec r)\delta(-ct)=\frac1c\delta(\vec r)\delta(t)$

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS:**

Use the product rule for the Laplacian,

$$\nabla^2 (fg)=f\nabla^2 g+2\nabla f\cdot\nabla g+g\nabla^2f$$

with $f=\frac1r$ and $g=\delta(r-ct)$ along with the distributional equality

$$\nabla^2 \left(\frac1r\right)=-4\pi \delta(\vec r)$$

to find

$$\nabla^2\left(\frac{\delta(r-ct)}{r}\right)=\frac1r \nabla^2\delta(r-ct)-\frac2{r^2}\delta'(r-ct)-4\pi \delta(\vec r)\delta(r-ct)$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: yes i could finish now. thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @petermafai Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.